# breakpoints location change by modifying code

Tags: eclipse, algorithm, breakpoints

in eclipse and Visual studio, I find that placing a break point in certain line

```
  1- public class HelloWorld {
* 2- public static void main(String[] args) {
  3-    System.out.println("Hello, World");
  4- }
  5- }
```

if i placed breakpoint in line 3 and edited the code in notepad editor to add anything before that line then open back eclipse it'll point automatically to line 4 with the breakpoint as it adapted the line I chose before.

```
  1- public class HelloWorld {
  2- public static void main(String[] args) {
  3-    int i=0;
* 4-    System.out.println("Hello, World");
  5- }
  6- }
```

I need to know the location of the code in eclipse source code that handle this case? or is there any known algorithm that is used to adapt the breakpoint location after modifying the code ?

I don't think it searches for the line by text as when I change the content of the line it does go to it w'ever the change

Comment: Is your question only about modifications with an other editor outside from Eclipse?

Comment: no, If I modified it within eclipse, it sense the new line too and place the breakpoint correctly. what I actually want is to understand how this is done ?

Answer (score 0):

To control syntax, types etc., modern IDE creates tree-model of your source code (similar what compiler does before compiling).

The changes in code - inside or outside IDE - does not require rebuilding the entire tree, therefore it is able to remember at which node of "source tree" the breakpoint is, rather than remembering only line.

It is quite handy, if you are actively debugging and changing the code, you do not have to move all your breakpoint up or down, if the code few lines up or down.

---

It looks [like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Abstract_syntax_tree_for_Euclidean_algorithm.svg/400px-Abstract_syntax_tree_for_Euclidean_algorithm.svg.png) , the breakpoint is (probably) attached not to line, but to one of those nodes.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
How each line is stroed in the tree? what type of node that makes it reachable even if I changed the line contents ?
can you clarify your point ? also, if you can refer to any open source code that does such thing